# Inheritance classes (Java), explicit constructor error message

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation, extends

so I am trying to learn about inheritance classes.

First I created a class called Box to calculate the area of the box.

Then I created a TestBox Class in which I have created a box object called fedEx.

**Box Class:**

```
public class Box {
    private String boxName;

    public void calculateArea(int length, int width) {
        System.out.println("Area of " + getBoxInfo() + (length * width));
    }

    public Box(String boxName) {
        this.boxName = boxName;
    }

    public String getBoxInfo() {
        return boxName;
    }
}
```

**TestBox Class:**

```
public class TestBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box fedEx = new Box("fedEx");
        fedEx.calculateArea(23, 2);
    }
}
```

So Far if I run this code everything works out fine and my print screen shows
Area of Fedex 46

So now I went to create a new class called NewBox and used "extends" to inherit the methods from the class Box, this class is used to calculate Volume

**NewBox Class:**

```
public class NewBox extends Box {

    public void calculateVolume(int length, int width, int height) {
        System.out.println("Volume = " + (length * width * height));
    }
}
```

Now to test this I created a new object in my TestBox class called UPS, now my TestBox class looks like this:

```
public class TestBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box fedEx = new Box("fedEx");
        fedEx.calculateArea(23, 2);

        NewBox UPS = new NewBox("UPS");
        UPS.calculateArea(3, 2);
        UPS.calculateVolume(3, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this program I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor NewBox(String) is undefined
    at day3.inheritence.TestBox.main(TestBox.java:10)
```

I am using eclipse as my IDE.

What can I do to fix my code, and what does the error message mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NewBox has to have a constructor that forwards to the parent class's constructor.  Try this:

```
public class NewBox extends Box{ 

  public NewBox(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  public void calculateVolume(int length, int width, int height){ 
    System.out.println("Volume = " + (length*width*height));
  }
}
```

Comment: So this worked, but I do not understand why, do you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: In Java, parent class constructors are not inherited by child classes.  So you have to create a constructor on the child class and then tell that constructor to call the constructor on the parent class.  The "super" keyword is what references the parent class.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html for more info on the super keyword.

Answer (score 1):

add below in your `NewBox` class.

```
public NewBox(String name){
    super(name);
}
```

Now `NewBox` becomes

```
public class NewBox extends Box{
    public NewBox(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void calculateVolume(int length, int width, int height){
        System.out.println("Volume = " + (length*width*height));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your parent class(Box) is having a parametrized constructor your child class(NewBox) must have a parametrized constructor which then in turn should call its super constructor.So add the below constructor in NewBox class

```
public NewBox(String name){
   super(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first talk about [default constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).  A default constructor is *implicitly* declared if you do not create a constructor yourself.

```
public class SomeClass {
    // field and method declarations to follow
}
```

If you declare a constructor, then there is no default constructor; there is only the declared constructor(s).

```
public class Box {

    private final String boxName;

    public Box(String boxName) {
        this.boxName = boxName;
    }
}
```

With inheritance, if the child is implicitly declaring a default constructor but the parent does *not* have a constructor with a similar signature, a compile-time error occurs.

More specifically:

> **It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.**

In your case, add the `super` keyword, and pass in the argument straight to the parent.

```
public class NewBox extends Box {
    public NewBox(String boxName) {
        super(boxName);
    }
}
```

---

As another example, the class `Beta` will compile just fine because `Alpha` declares a constructor that matches the default constructor's signature, but `Delta` will not compile because `Gamma` does not have a constructor that matches.

```
class Alpha {
    public Alpha() {

    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {

}

class Gamma {
    private final int count;

    public Gamma(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}

class Delta extends Gamma {

}
```

This can be fixed by providing a no-arg constructor to `Gam

```
class Gamma {
    private final int count;

    public Gamma(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Gamma() {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class NewBox should be something like this

```
public class NewBox extends Box{

    public NewBox(String boxName){
       super(boxName);        
    }

    public void calculateVolume(int length, int width, int height){
        System.out.println("Volume = " + (length*width*height));
    }
}
```

By writing `NewBox UPS = new NewBox("UPS");`in your TestBox, **JVM is expecting  constructor with string as parameter in NewBox, but it is missing there**. So we create a constructor which is having string as parameter in NewBox, and in that constructor we write `super(boxName)` which says to call the constructor of the parent class, here Box.